# How to find the indices of the maximum in each line, a concatenation of rows, in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know if this is simple or not or if it is asked before or not. (I searched but did not find the correct way to do it. I have found `numpy.argmax` and `numpy.amax` but I am not able to use them correctly.)

I have a numpy array (it is a `CxKxN` matrix) as follows (`C=K=N=3`):

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 1, 4],
        [4, 3, 3]],

       [[2, 1, 1],
        [1, 3, 1],
        [3, 4, 2]],

       [[5, 2, 1],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 1, 2]]])
```

I would like to find the indices of the maximum elements across each line. A line is the concatenation of the three (`C`) rows of each matrix. In other words, the `i`-th line is the concatenation of the `i`-th row in the first matrix, the `i`-th row in the second matrix, ..., until the `i`-th row in the `C`-th matrix.

For example, the first line is

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1]
```

So I would like to return

```
[2, 0, 0] # the index of the maximum in the first line
```

and

```
[0, 1, 2] # the index of the maximum in the second line
```

and

```
[0, 2, 0] # the index of the maximum in the third line
```

or

```
[1, 2, 1] # the index of the maximum in the third line
```

or

```
[2, 2, 0] # the index of the maximum in the third line
```

Now, I am trying this

```
np.argmax(a[:,0,:], axis=None) # for the first line
```

It returns `6` and

```
np.argmax(a[:,1,:], axis=None)
```

and it returns `2` and

```
np.argmax(a[:,2,:], axis=None)
```

and it returns `0`

but I am able to convert these numbers to indices like `6 = (2,0,0)`, etc.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match with the reality. Second line is `[2, 1, 4], [1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 3]`. How do you get `[0, 1, 2]` then? The same applies to your all other 4 lines. It is not clear what is the second line? How do you construct it? How many total lines do you have? Only 3? You have to clarify all these questions first. If you are joining 1st row from all three arrays in one line, 2nd rows from all three arrays in second line and all 3rd rows from all subarrays in third line, then you only have three lines in total. How do you get 6 lines then?

Comment: `[0,1,2]` because `4` is in the first `3x3` matrix, it is in the second row of this matrix and it is in the third column of this matrix. The `i`-th line is the concatenation of the `i`-th row in the first matrix, the `i`-th row in the second matrix, ..., until the `i`-th row in the `C`-th matrix.

Comment: What is there are multiple entries of `4`?

Comment: Yes, I only have three lines, I just printed ties (in the third line).

Comment: If there is a tie, I can select any one arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an transpose and reshape I get your 'rows'

```
In [367]: arr.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(3,9)
Out[367]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2]])
In [368]: np.argmax(_, axis=1)
Out[368]: array([6, 2, 0])
```

These max are same as yours.  The same indices, but in a (3,3) array:

```
In [372]: np.unravel_index([6,2,0],(3,3))
Out[372]: (array([2, 0, 0]), array([0, 2, 0]))
```

Join them with middle dimension range:

```
In [373]: tup = (_[0],np.arange(3),_[1])
In [374]: np.transpose(tup)
Out[374]: 
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

Comment: How to do this for general `CxKxN` array?